# Why is my login menu not working here? (first scanf seems to be the problem but i cant fix it)

Tags: c

```
    int login_user()
{
    wrong:
    printf("-------------Login-------------\n");
    int loop,dev;
    char usernmcmpr[30],pswdcmpr[4],loginchoice,test[30];
    printf("Username:");
    scanf(" %s",&usernmcmpr);
    printf("Password:");
    scanf(" %s", &pswdcmpr);
    printf("1. %s\n",username);
    printf("2. %s",usernmcmpr);
    if(strcmp(password,pswdcmpr) == 0 && strcmp(username,usernmcmpr) == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("-------------Main Menu-------------\n");
        printf("a.Calculate Cost\nb.Payment\nc.Recepit\nd.Exit\n");
        scanf(" %c", &loginchoice);
        if (loginchoice == 'a')
        {
        system("cls");
        calculate_cost();
        }
        else if (loginchoice == 'b')
        {
        system("cls");
        payment();
        }
        else if (loginchoice == 'c')
        {
            system("cls");
            receipt();
        }
        else if (loginchoice == 'd')
        {
            keep_Looping = 1;
            system("cls");
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("-------------Error-------------\n");
            printf("Invalid input please try again\n");
            goto wrong;
            clear();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        goto wrong;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It used to work and then all of a sudden it stopped, don't know why i didn't even change the code in this function nor did i change anything related to it. Really can't tell what is wrong.

Comment: Unless you password is three characters or less, this has little hope of "working" no matter what. `pswdcmpr[4]` only leaves room for a 3-char entry (or shorter) accounting or the terminating nullchar. Anything longer and you breach your array and invoke undefined behavior, since your `%s` has no length limit. And fyi, *all* of those string `scanf` arguments are wrong. The leading `&` on each of them is erroneous.

Comment: Not your problem, but someone appears to have given you an overzealous rule in an attempt to work around `scanf`'s idiosyncrasies.  Yes, you do want an extra space in `" %c"`.  But you don't need it in `"%s"` or most of the other format specifiers.

Comment: Only for `%c` or `%[]` or `%n` unless you intend to read the whitespace character (which is why they are an exception to the auto-filtering of other format specifiers).

Comment: Always a bug: not checking the return value from scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usernmcmpr is a char array which is basically a char* under the hood. Since usernmcmpr is already a pointer you want `scanf(" %s", usernmcmpr);` instead of `scanf(" %s",&usernmcmpr);`. Same for your other char arrays.

Furthermore, you should be more cautious about buffer overflow problems as currently the user can enter more than your arrays can hold. See [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)